# How to create navigation bar item in the custom Navigation Bar in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I have created one custom view and added a web view as subview of that custom view. And i have created one navigation bar in programmatically. Now i want to create one Left or Right navigation bar buttons in that view.

```
navigBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

navigBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[self.view addSubview:navigBar];

UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(homeButtonAction)];

navigBar.rightBarButtonItem = homeButton; // it's not supports
```

How can i create navigation bar item in the custom navigation bar?, i want to remove the custom view. So please Help me out!

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On your navigationbar reference you could invoke the two methods:

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

In your custom view controller class write something like this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = yourButton;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourSecondButton;
```

So you could write something like this:

```
[myNavBarReference pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html

You would invoke methods to self.navigationItem.

Answer (score 0):

`rightBarButton` is defined for `UINavigationItem`. See the documentation for the  [`UINavigationItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) and for the [`UINavigationBar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) (Specially *Adding Content to a Navigation Bar*).

The method to use is `- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated`