# Adding a button with backgroundimage and action in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I need to add a button with no title and background image and perform action when clicked on it .I need to add a button to navigation bar.
I have made the navigation bar like this :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
    self.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

I can see the white navigation bar to it.How can I add a button to it with image and action ?

Comment: check out this link may be it will help you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768778/how-to-create-navigation-bar-item-in-the-custom-navigation-bar-in-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view:-

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 75.0, 40.0)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbutton;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
    self.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

   UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]
                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                        target:self action:@selector(yourButtonPressMethodName:)];   
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;//use rightBarButtonItem if you want to add button on right dife
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use code below:

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBar=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:@"img.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(methodname:)];
```